# Can I resolve a type to a custom name in Aurelia?

Tags: dependency-injection, aurelia

I wrote this

```
@singleton("httpBasicAuth")
export class HttpBasicAuthentication {...}
```

but when I call

```
container.get("httpBasicAuth")
```

it simply returns `"httpBasicAuth"`, I see that the `container._resolvers` has `{"httpBasicAuth" => StrategyResolver}`, and `hasResolver("httpBasicAuth")` returns `true`

How can I retrieve `HttpBasicAuthentication` with string key `httpBasicAuth`?